# Print /var/log/foo to terminal screen

Tags: linux

I have written a few services running on my laptop which writes log data to amongst other /var/log/messages. Is it possible to get any updates to this or other log files to also write data to screen? When I say screen, I mean the terminal window that comes up when entering Alt+Fx buttons.

What I want is instead of the login message, I want data from one or more specific log files to be written to this screen automatically and that it will not be possible to log in using these screens.

I don't automatically run X and therefore still use these shortcuts a lot to get information. Normally I press Alt+Fx, log in and do tail -f /var/log/foo.

This might be relevant. Using Debian and Fedora, bash is the terminal of choice, but I am capable of using others as well.

Comment: We need to know what you want to achieve. Do you want to protect the system and use it as a live log reader? Do you want to use it for your own use?

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully that is similar to what you are looking for, I just tried it with a Knoppix BootCD,

```
tail -f /var/log/Xorg.0.log | tee /dev/tty2 > /dev/null
```

Comment: It might be. I can put that into one of the scripts that run as root and that will automatically start printing to screen without interruption from any other source?

Comment: @Mogget - I don't see any problem on running the command inside a script unless it is a recurring task (for example, an hourly cron job).  In this case you'd better run it once during start up.  On the other hand, it may not be trivial if you want to make it access these `/dev/ttyX` exclusively.